# Process command Issue (PSBeginner Issue)

Tags: process, kill

first of all sorry for this lame question ,after killing it is still runinng , i am a beginner ,

```
rohit@something:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4596 pts/1    00:00:02 bash
 4618 pts/1    00:00:02 du
 4620 pts/1    00:00:00 du
 4675 pts/1    00:00:00 wget
 4875 pts/1    00:00:08 find
 4876 pts/1    00:00:09 find
 5396 pts/1    00:00:04 find
 5402 pts/1    00:00:06 find
 5405 pts/1    00:00:14 find
 5409 pts/1    00:00:02 find
 5626 pts/1    00:00:01 bash
 6210 pts/1    00:00:00 ps

rohit@something:~$ kill 4618

rohit@something:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4596 pts/1    00:00:02 bash
 4618 pts/1    00:00:02 du
 4620 pts/1    00:00:00 du
 4675 pts/1    00:00:00 wget
 4875 pts/1    00:00:08 find
 4876 pts/1    00:00:09 find
 5396 pts/1    00:00:04 find
 5402 pts/1    00:00:06 find
 5405 pts/1    00:00:14 find
 5409 pts/1    00:00:02 find
 5626 pts/1    00:00:01 bash
 6211 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 0):

If a normal kill does not work you might kill it with signal KILL

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

so in your case

```
kill -9 4618
```

More on kill can be found in the related [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/kill.1.html)